# Early return from react useEffect custom hook is not getting destructure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react custom hook which is using `useEffect`. This hook is supposed to fetch data from **api** using JS `fetch`. Now, i want to return api or error data based on the situation and then destructure the value on the component where this hook is called. Below is the code of my custom hook

```
export const useGetData = (url, body) => {
const [state, setState] = useState([]);
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'Post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
    setState({response});
  ).catch(error =>
    console.error('Error:', error);
    setErrorMsg(error);
    return errorMsg;
  );
}
}, [url, body]);
return state;
}
```

and here is how it has been called from react component

```
  let data = { state: '', errorMsg: '' };
  data = useGetData('url', 'body');
```

Now, the when the api call is success, i am able to get correct data in `data` but not able to get error data in case of failure. My custom hook is early returning in case of error but the same not able to destructure in react component from where its called. What's wrong here?

Comment: Aren't those data types incongruous with what they expect? state expects an array, errorMsg expects an object - you're providing strings in both cases.

Comment: One, you are only returning `state` from the hook and not the error. Second, you are setting state outside of `fetch` where `response` isn't available

Comment: @rrd What's the right way to it? I want to persist the success api call data and juts update the error ones?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason you are not seeing the error data is that you are not returning `errorMsg` from your `useGetData` hook.

Try this:

```
    export const useGetData = (url, body) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'Post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(response => {
         let data = response.json())
         setData(data);
        }  
      ).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        setErrorMsg(error);
      });
    }
    }, [url, body]);
    return {data, errorMsg};
    }
```

and in your component access the data like this:

```
  const {data, errorMsg} = useGetData('url', 'body');
```

Hope this helps